# ¿Como es gráficamente un sistema fuertemente acoplado de una BD distribuida?

Tags: base-de-datos

Actualmente tengo que crear un `diagrama distribuido` de una base de datos a través de un `sistema fuertemente acoplado` mostrando la `asignación`, `distribución` y `replicación` de los datos, la cuestión es respecto a como representarlo de esa forma.

Encontré que un `sistema fuertemente acoplado` esta representado de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y un `diagrama distribuido` esta representado de la siguiente manera (o simplemente así representan una base de datos distribuida):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Independientemente de la base de datos, como puede ser un ejemplo de esto, ya que eh investigado en bastantes sitios web y no encuentro algo que sea realmente un `diagrama distribuido` a través de un `sistema fuertemente acoplado`.

De cualquier manera, mi `base de datos` es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que es un poco confuso, pero el enunciado dice lo siguiente: Diseñar el `diagrama distribuido` de la `base de datos` del proyecto (mostrando la `asignación`, `distribución` y `replicación` de los datos) a través de un `sistema fuertemente acoplado`.

Lo mas próximo que encontré fue lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]